# Project embedded document key value, based on condition in mongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongo collection called tickets and we are storing ticket details in similar structure documents like this:

```
    [
      {
        "status": "PAUSED",
        "lifecycle_dates": {
          "OPEN": "d1",
          "CLOSED": "d2",
          "PAUSED": "d3"
        }
      },
      {
        "status": "OPEN",
        "lifecycle_dates": {
          "OPEN": "d1",
          "PAUSED": "d3"
        }
      },
      {
        "status": "CLOSED",
        "lifecycle_dates": {
          "OPEN": "d1",
          "CLOSED": "d2"
        }
      }
    ]
```

I need to fetch the data which says current status of ticket and status date on.

and I want to project data like :

```
[
  {
    "status": "PAUSED",
    "lifecycle_date": "d3"
  },
  {
    "status": "OPEN",
    "lifecycle_date": "d1"
  },
  {
    "status": "CLOSED",
    "lifecycle_date": "d2"
  }
]
```

How can I project single lifecycle date based on current status in mongo aggregation pipeline? 
something like this:

```
{
    $project : {
        "status" : 1,
        "lifecycle_date" : $lifecycle_dates[$status]
    }
}
```

couldn't find any reference or similar problem in [mongo reference document here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/)

**current mongo version : 3.2**

Comment: Use `$project` here... `[{$project:{status:1,lifecycle_date:'$lifecycle_dates.PAUSED'}}]`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet sorry question wasn't clear before, I have updated it. can you take another look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer :**

Since you need to fetch the `date` as per the `status`, you can use this aggregate query :

```
db.test.aggregate([ 
{
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        status : 1,
        lifecycle_date : { $cond: [ {$eq : ["$status","OPEN"]}, "$lifecycle_dates.OPEN", { $cond: [ {$eq : ["$status","CLOSED"]}, "$lifecycle_dates.CLOSED", { $cond: [ {$eq : ["$status","PAUSED"]}, "$lifecycle_dates.PAUSED", "-1" ]} ]} ]}
    }
}])
```

This is compatible with Mongo 3.2 as well.

Output :

```
{ "status" : "PAUSED", "lifecycle_date" : "d3" }
{ "status" : "OPEN", "lifecycle_date" : "d1" }
{ "status" : "CLOSED", "lifecycle_date" : "d2" }
```

=========================================================================

This answer was for the previous question -

Use this aggregate :

```
db.test.aggregate([
{
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        status : 1,
        lifecycle_date : "$lifecycle_dates.PAUSED"
    }
}
])
```

Output :

```
{ "status" : "PAUSED", "lifecycle_date" : "d3" }
```

Comment: Problem is I don't know which is the current status, there are three status possible 'OPEN', 'CLOSED' and 'PAUSED', their respective dates are stored in an object called 'lifecycle_dates'. while retrieving I just want lifecycle date based on current status.

Comment: I have updated my answer, as per your update, kindly verify. It's compatible with Mongo 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "status": 1,
    "lifecycle_date": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": { "$objectToArray": "$lifecycle_dates" },
          "as": "life",
          "cond": { "$eq": ["$$life.k", "$status"] }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "status": 1,
    "lifecycle_date": "$lifecycle_date.v"
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, seems like this should, but **$objectToArray is not present in mongo 3.2** is there any way to do it in v3.2?

Comment: yes, you have to upgrade to 3.6 or above to use this... check it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/X3lQ43Xkj5i

Answer (score 0):

```
db.tickets.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $project: {
                "status": 1,
                _id: 0,
                "lifecycle_dates": {
                    $switch: {
                        branches: [{
                                case: {
                                    $eq: ["$status", "PAUSED"]
                                },
                                then: "$lifecycle_dates.PAUSED"
                            },
                            {
                                case: {
                                    $eq: ["$status", "OPEN"]
                                },
                                then: "$lifecycle_dates.OPEN"
                            },
                            {
                                case: {
                                    $eq: ["$status", "CLOSED"]
                                },
                                then: "$lifecycle_dates.OPEN"
                            }
                        ],

                    }
                }
            }
        },
    ])
```